# No such file or directory while working with Glove (Deep learning)

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am currently trying to add a preloaded embedded from Glove from a model and can't seem to load the glove text file to parse it's data. I always get the file not found error.

My code is as follows:

```
outname = 'glove.6B.100d.txt'
outdir = './Downloads'
if not os.path.exists(outdir):
    os.mkdir(outdir)
fullname = os.path.join(outdir, outname)

def getEmbeddedMatrix(num_words, embedding_size):
  embeddings_index = {}
  with open(fullname, "r") as file_directory:
    for line in file_directory:
        values = line.split()
        word = values[0]
        coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
        embeddings_index[word] = coefs

  embedding_matrix = np.zeros((num_words, embedded_size))
  for word, index in imdb.get_word_index.items():
      if index >= num_words:
          continue
      embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
      if embedding_vector is not None:
          embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
            
  return embedding_matrix
```

The error message I get is as follows:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Downloads/glove.6B.100d.txt'
```

Any suggestions on what to do here? The .txt file is currently in my Downloads and I am using Google Colab

Edit:

I have also tried doing the following but it still throws up the same error

```
def getEmbeddedMatrix(num_words, embedding_size):
  embeddings_index = {}
  File_object = open(r"/Users/______/downloads/glove.6B.100d.txt","r")
  with File_object as file_directory:
    for line in file_directory:
        values = line.split()
        word = values[0]
        coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
        embeddings_index[word] = coefs

  embedding_matrix = np.zeros((num_words, embedded_size))
  for word, index in imdb.get_word_index.items():
      if index >= num_words:
          continue
      embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
      if embedding_vector is not None:
          embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
            
  return embedding_matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload the text file at google-colab's working folder, instead of your Desktop's Downloads folder.

See [this](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb) link.

Comment: How do we do this? Thanks

Comment: I think that there also is an upload button. edit: Yeap, I just checked, you can do drag and drop.